# How to calculate Total average response time

Tags: jmeter

Below are the results

```
    sampler_label count average   median   90%_line     min      max

    Transaction1    2   61774     61627   61921        61627    61921
    Transaction2    4   82          61     190          15       190
    Transaction3    4   1862       1317   3612          1141    3612
    Transaction4    4   1242        915   1602          911      1602
    Transaction5    4   692         608    906          423      906
    Transaction6    4   2764        2122  4748          1182    4748
    Transaction7    4   9369        9029  11337         7198    11337
    Transaction8    4   1245        890    2168          834    2168
    Transaction9    4   3475        2678    4586        2520    4586
    TOTAL          34   6073       1381     9913         15     61921
```

My question here is how is total average response time is being calculated (which is 6073)?

Like in my result I want to exclude transaction1 response time and then want to calculate Total average response time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Total Avg Response time = `((s1*t1) + (s2*t2)...)/s`

```
s1 = No of times transaction 1 was executed
t1 = Avg response time for transaction 1
s2 = No of times transaction 2 was executed
t2 = Avg response time for transaction 2
s = Total no of samples (s1+s2..)
```

In your case, except transaction1 all other transactions have been executed 4 times. So, simple avg of (82, 1862, 1242...) should give the result you wanted.